# How to get main args in JavaFX fallback class

Tags: java, javafx-2

In a JavaFX application i want to be able to get to the command line arguments in the fallback class, is there a way to to that?

When i create the JavaFX application i set a custom fallback class

```
<fx:application id="MyApplication" name="My Application" 
        mainClass="MyApplication.Main" 
        fallbackClass="MyApplication.Fallback"
        toolkit="swing"/>
```

My custom fallback class looks like

```
public class Fallback extends javax.swing.JApplet{
    public Fallback(){
        MyApplication.Main.main(new String[]{});
    }
}
```

The fallback class just start the same application, it works as all JavaFX componentes are used via reflection when available, but don't know how can i get the original args passed to the application.

Comment: try to use [Application.Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.Parameters.html) class

Comment: Not sure how this would work, the fallback class is for non JavaFX support and Application.Parameters is part of JavaFX

Comment: indeed, then may be this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958318/is-it-possible-to-get-the-command-used-to-launch-the-jvm-in-java