# How can I find out the command line arguments of a running application?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, process, command-line-arguments

I wish to know if an application is running and what commands line arguments were passed on to it, if so.

While I can find out if the application is indeed running, I am not sure how I can retrieve the command line arguments which were passed on to it.

Is there a way to figure this out using `C++` or `Qt`?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the operating system (unless there's something portable in Qt). On Linux, you can read them from `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`

Comment: That is for the current running process. I wish to know, in my application A, the command line argument(s) which might have been passed to an application B, which is already running.

Comment: This linked [article might help](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19685/Get-Process-Info-with-NtQueryInformationProcess), you can also use [WMI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/25/9928372.aspx), you would have to translate the script here though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589431/getting-the-command-line-arguments-of-another-process-in-windows